# How to create crosstab with two field in bigquery with standart or legacy sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get two columns from table and create a crosstab to see how many product bought in which product category for each customer.
Here is an example data from my table:

```
Row     Customer_ID     Style    
 1      MEM014          BLS87    
 2      KAR810          DR126    
 3      NIKE61          MMQ5     
 4      NIKE61          MMQ5     
 5      STT019          BLS83    
 6      STT019          BLS84    
 7      STT019          BLS87
```

And I want to get result table like this:

```
Customer - DR126 - MMQ5 - BLS83 - BLS84 - BLS87
MEM014       0       0      0       0       1
KAR810       1       0      0       0       0
NIKE61       0       2      0       0       0
STT019       0       0      1       1       1
```

Comment: Did you try searching for questions and answers about "pivot" in SQL? There are many similar past questions that should show how to write this query.

Comment: I did @ElliottBrossard pivot command not working on bigquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

**Step #1** - generate pivot query

```sql
  #standardSQL
  SELECT CONCAT(
  "SELECT Customer_ID,", 
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT("COUNTIF(Style='", Style, "') ", Style)), 
  " FROM `project.dataset.your_table` GROUP BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer_ID")
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Style
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
    ORDER BY Style
  )
```

If you run it with dummy data from your question like below

```sql
  #standardSQL
  WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
    SELECT 'MEM014' Customer_ID, 'BLS87' Style UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'KAR810', 'DR126' UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'NIKE61', 'MMQ5' UNION ALL     
    SELECT 'NIKE61', 'MMQ5' UNION ALL     
    SELECT 'STT019', 'BLS83' UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'STT019', 'BLS84' UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'STT019', 'BLS87' 
  )
  SELECT CONCAT(
  "SELECT Customer_ID,", 
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT("COUNTIF(Style='", Style, "') ", Style)), 
  " FROM `project.dataset.your_table` GROUP BY Customer_ID")
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Style
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
    ORDER BY Style
  )
```

you will get following pivot query

```sql
SELECT Customer_ID,COUNTIF(Style='BLS83') BLS83,COUNTIF(Style='BLS84') BLS84,COUNTIF(Style='BLS87') BLS87,COUNTIF(Style='DR126') DR126,COUNTIF(Style='MMQ5') MMQ5 FROM `project.dataset.your_table` GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

**Step #2** - run generated pivot query

if you run it against your dummy data - you get expected result

```sql
Row Customer_ID BLS83   BLS84   BLS87   DR126   MMQ5     
1   KAR810      0       0       0       1       0    
2   MEM014      0       0       1       0       0    
3   NIKE61      0       0       0       0       2    
4   STT019      1       1       1       0       0
```

***Note 1***: Above assumes your Style names comply with column names convention (those in your example do). If not - you will need to escape not supported characters and so on (easy adjustment for step 1)
***Note 2***: Maximum unresolved query length is 256 KB. So if your Style names are similar to those in your example - above solution will support around 8500 styles, which should be less than limit (10K?) for number of columns in table

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
       sum(case when style = 'DR126' then 1 else 0 end) as DR126,
       sum(case when style = 'MMQ5' then 1 else 0 end) as MMQ5,
       . . .
from t
group by customer;
```

This works if you have the exact list of styles.  If not, then you should be thinking in terms of arrays for the result set.

EDIT:

You can create an array of structs if that better suits your purpose:

```
select customer, array_agg(cs) as styles
from (select customer, style, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by customer
     ) cs
group by customer;
```

What you cannot do is have a query return a variable number of columns.  For that, you need dynamic SQL and a programming language.

Comment: there are thousands of style item. I think hardcoding is not a good idea?

Comment: @yigitozmen this is what I was suggesting with using a pivot. You need to list the item names, since queries cannot have dynamic column lists.